'use client' component not updating when user logs in
I'm new to the Next.js framework and have the issue described in the title.
app/Layout.tsx
import '@/app/ui/globals.css';
import { inter } from '@/app/ui/fonts';
import AppBar from '@/app/ui/app-bar';
import { getTickers } from '@/app/lib/tickers';
import { auth } from '@/auth';
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';

export default async function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const tickers = await getTickers();
  const session = await auth();

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${inter.className} antialiased`}>
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
          <AppBar options={tickers} />
          {children}
        </SessionProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

app/ui/app-bar.tsx <- The 'use client' component that doesn't update.
'use client'

import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { signOut, useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

export default function AppBar({ options }: { options: { label: string, value: string }[] }) {
    const { data: session } = useSession();
    const user = session?.user;
    const [isUserMenuOpen, setIsUserMenuOpen] = useState(false);
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
    const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState<{ label: string, value: string }[]>([]);
    const router = useRouter();
    const menuRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        function handleClickOutside(event: MouseEvent) {
            if (menuRef.current && !menuRef.current.contains(event.target as Node)) {
                setIsUserMenuOpen(false);
            }
        }

        document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
        };
    }, []);

    const handleSearch = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const term = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
        setSearchTerm(term);

        if (term.length > 0) {
            const filtered = options.filter(option =>
                option.label.toLowerCase().includes(term) ||
                option.value.toLowerCase().includes(term)
            );
            setSearchResults(filtered);
        } else {
            setSearchResults([]);
        }
    };

    const handleSelectOption = (value: string) => {
        setSearchTerm('');
        setSearchResults([]);
        router.push(`/companies/${value}`);
    };

    const getInitials = (firstName: string | null | undefined, lastName: string | null | undefined) => {
        const first = firstName ? firstName[0] : '';
        const last = lastName ? lastName[0] : '';
        return (first + last).toUpperCase();
    };

    const handleLogout = async () => {
        await signOut({ redirect: false });
        window.location.href = '/login'; // <- Forcing a hard refresh here to update the app bar
    };

    const userInitials = user ? getInitials(user.first_name, user.last_name) : 'G'; // G for Guest User

    return (
        <nav className="bg-blue-600 p-4">
            <div className="container mx-auto flex items-center justify-between">
                <Link href="/" className="text-white text-xl font-bold">
                    Company Name
                </Link>

                <div className="flex-grow mx-4 relative">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Ticker or company name"
                        className="w-full p-2 bg-blue-500 text-white placeholder-blue-200 border border-blue-400 rounded focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-300 focus:border-blue-400"
                        value={searchTerm}
                        onChange={handleSearch}
                    />
                    {searchResults.length > 0 && (
                        <ul className="absolute z-10 w-full bg-white mt-1 rounded-md shadow-lg max-h-60 overflow-auto">
                            {searchResults.map((result) => (
                                <li
                                    key={result.value}
                                    className="px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 cursor-pointer"
                                    onClick={() => handleSelectOption(result.value)}
                                >
                                    {result.label} ({result.value})
                                </li>
                            ))}
                        </ul>
                    )}
                </div>

                <div className="relative" ref={menuRef}>
                    {user ? (
                        <div className="relative ml-3">
                            <div>
                                <button
                                    type="button"
                                    className="flex rounded-full bg-blue-700 text-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-white focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-blue-600"
                                    id="user-menu-button"
                                    aria-expanded="false"
                                    aria-haspopup="true"
                                    onClick={() => setIsUserMenuOpen(!isUserMenuOpen)}
                                >
                                    <span className="sr-only">Open user menu</span>
                                    <div className="h-10 w-10 rounded-full bg-white flex items-center justify-center text-blue-600 font-bold text-lg shadow-lg border-2 border-blue-300 transition-all duration-200 hover:scale-110">
                                        {userInitials}
                                    </div>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            {isUserMenuOpen && (
                                <div className="absolute right-0 z-10 mt-2 w-56 origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white py-1 shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none" role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="user-menu-button" tabIndex={-1}>
                                    <div className="px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-500 border-b border-gray-200">
                                        {user?.first_name} {user?.last_name}
                                    </div>
                                    <Link href="/settings/account" className="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100" role="menuitem" tabIndex={-1}>
                                        Account
                                    </Link>
                                    <Link href="/settings/security" className="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100" role="menuitem" tabIndex={-1}>
                                        Password & Security
                                    </Link>
                                    <Link href="/settings/billing" className="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100" role="menuitem" tabIndex={-1}>
                                        Subscription & Billing
                                    </Link>
                                    <div className="border-t border-gray-200 my-1"></div>
                                    <button
                                    onClick={handleLogout}
                                        className="block w-full text-left px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100"
                                        role="menuitem"
                                        tabIndex={-1}
                                    >
                                        Sign Out
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            )}
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <Link href="/login" className="text-white hover:bg-blue-700 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">
                            Sign In
                        </Link>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
}

auth.ts
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { authConfig } from './auth.config';
import { z } from 'zod';
import { sql } from '@vercel/postgres';
import type { User } from '@/app/lib/definitions';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

async function getUser(email: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
    try {
        const user = await sql<User>`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=${email}`;
        return user.rows[0];
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch user:', error);
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch user.');
    }
}

export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
    ...authConfig,
    providers: [
        Credentials({
            async authorize(credentials) {
                const parsedCredentials = z
                    .object({ email: z.string().email(), password: z.string().min(6) })
                    .safeParse(credentials);

                if (parsedCredentials.success) {
                    const { email, password } = parsedCredentials.data;
                    const user = await getUser(email);
                    if (!user) return null;
                    if (!user.email_verified) {
                        throw new Error('Please verify your email before logging in.');
                    }
                    const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
                    if (passwordsMatch) {
                        return {
                            id: user.id,
                            email: user.email,
                            first_name: user.first_name,
                            last_name: user.last_name,
                        };
                    }
                }
                
                console.log('Invalid credentials');
                return null;
            },
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            //console.log('auth.ts user, token', user, token);
            if (user) {
                token.first_name = user.first_name;
                token.last_name = user.last_name;
            }

            //console.log('auth.ts changed token', token);
            return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            //console.log('auth.ts session, token', session, token);
            if (session.user) {
                session.user.first_name = token.first_name as string;
                session.user.last_name = token.last_name as string;
            }
            //console.log('auth.ts changed session', session);
            return session;
        },
    }
});

auth.config.ts <- Where the redirect happens
import type { NextAuthConfig } from 'next-auth';

export const authConfig = {
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ auth, request: { nextUrl } }) {
      const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user;
      const isOnLoginPage = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/login')
      const isOnRegisterPage = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/register')

      if (isLoggedIn) {
        if (isOnLoginPage || isOnRegisterPage) {
          return Response.redirect(new URL('/', nextUrl));
        }
      }

      return true;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.first_name = user.first_name;
        token.last_name = user.last_name;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (session.user) {
        session.user.first_name = token.first_name as string;
        session.user.last_name = token.last_name as string;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
  providers: [],
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;

next-auth.d.ts
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';

declare module 'next-auth' {
    interface Session {
        user: {
            first_name: string;
            last_name: string;
        } & DefaultSession['user'];
    }

    interface User {
        first_name: string;
        last_name: string;
    }
}

declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
    /** Returned by the `jwt` callback and `getToken`, when using JWT sessions */
    interface JWT {
        first_name: string;
        last_name: string;
    }
}

app/api/[...nextauth]/route.ts
import { handlers } from "@/auth"
export const { GET, POST } = handlers

middleware.ts
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { authConfig } from './auth.config';
 
export default NextAuth(authConfig).auth;
 
export const config = {
  // https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)'],
};

app/login/page.tsx
import LoginForm from "@/app/ui/login-form";

export default function LoginPage() {
    return (
        <main>
            <LoginForm />
        </main>
    );
}

app/ui/login-form.tsx
'use client';

import Link from "next/link";
import { useActionState } from "react";
import { authenticate } from "../lib/actions";

export default function LoginForm() {
    const [errorMessage, formAction, isPending] = useActionState(
        authenticate,
        undefined,
    );

    return (
        <div className="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-50 py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div className="max-w-md w-full space-y-8">
                <div>
                    <div className="mx-auto h-12 w-12 rounded-full bg-blue-500 flex items-center justify-center">
                        <svg className="h-6 w-6 text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                            <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={2} d="M12 15v2m-6 4h12a2 2 0 002-2v-6a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v6a2 2 0 002 2zm10-10V7a4 4 0 00-8 0v4h8z" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <h2 className="mt-6 text-center text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">
                        Sign in
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <form action={formAction} className="mt-8 space-y-6">
                    <div className="rounded-md shadow-sm -space-y-px">
                        <div>
                            <label htmlFor="email" className="sr-only">Email address</label>
                            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" autoComplete="email" required className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-t-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm" placeholder="Email address" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label htmlFor="password" className="sr-only">Password</label>
                            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" autoComplete="current-password" required className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-b-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm" placeholder="Password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                        <div className="text-sm">
                            <Link href="#" className="font-medium text-blue-600 hover:text-blue-500">
                                Forgot your password?
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            className="group relative w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-blue-500"
                            disabled={isPending}>
                            {isPending ? 'Signing In...' : 'Sign In'}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    {errorMessage && (
                        <p className="mt-2 text-center text-sm text-red-600">
                            {errorMessage}
                        </p>
                    )}
                </form>

                <div className="text-sm text-center">
                    <Link href="/register" className="font-medium text-blue-600 hover:text-blue-500">
                        Don't have an account? Sign Up
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

I expected the AppBar to update automatically when user's are authenticated.
I am using Next.js 15.0.0-canary.106 with react & react-dom 19.0.0-rc-06d0b89e-20240801.
Can anyone point me as to why the AppBar doesn't update when user logs in successfully?

…and the strange thing is that user is indeed redirected to home but the url still is localhost:3000/login

…and I think that the problem lies in how the session object is updated. I think I need to simulate a hard refresh somehow but don’t know yet how to do that.
